# Algorithm to distribute over *part* of a Normal distribution

Tags: distribution, gaussian, normal-distribution

Is there a single pass algorithm that can produce numbers distributed over *part* of a normal (Gaussian) distribution?

I want to specify a base value (the center of the distribution), a standard deviation, and a min and max values.

For example I might want all values to be distributed between -0.5 and +1 standard deviations in the same ratio as would be found in a normal distribution (obviously increased to take into account the missing tails).

Obviously one can use a loop and only exit if the generated number was between the minimum and maximum, but that could go on for a long time if min/max are too close together or too far out along a tail.

I'm assuming a language with a Gaussian random number function (I'm using Java, but can read almost anything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute [erf](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) for the given Gaussian at the minimum and maximum points of interest, generate the random number (uniformly) between those two values, and take inverse `erf`.

I know the Apache library has an `erf` function in Java, see [here](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math/special/Erf.html), but I'm not sure where to point you for an inverse of `erf` (worst case, of course, you could calculate the latter with Newton-Raphson).

(I found an algorithm for inverse `erf` [here](http://home.online.no/~pjacklam/notes/invnorm/), with Java implementation, but can't vouch for its quality).